# java gae google cloud storage iterate over files in bucket

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have the following file structure in my publicly accessible bucket:

```
somedirs/somefiles.html
```

The html files show up in my bucket and I can access them in the browser and read/write from/to them in my application. I now want to iterate over all files (on gae with latest java sdk) to generate my sitemap.xml.

I was going for the following approach:

```
ListResult fileList = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(RetryParams.getDefaultInstance())
    .list("mybucket", new ListOptions.Builder().setRecursive(true).build());
String dir = null;
while (fileList.hasNext()) {
    ListItem file = fileList.next();
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        dir = file.getName();
        continue;
    } else if(dir == null)
        continue;
    //generate XML form file meta-data, name and dir name
}
```

My problem is that the file list seems to be empty hence my sitemap.xml is empty as well. The documentation and API documentation lack information on how to do it right.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `file.isDirectory()` never returns true. Instead `file.getName()` returns `somedir/somefile.html`.